# Validation Accuracy of CNN not increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have around 8200 images for face detection task. 4800 of them contain human faces. The other 3400 images contain images of 3D human face masks(which are made of rubber/latex), human cartoon faces, faces of monkeys. I want to detect whether the given image contains a real human face or not.

I have trained numerous networks, changing hyper parameters but every time my training accuracy shots up to over 98% and validation accuracy stays at around 60-70%. I have tried out networks containing 3-5 Conv layers and one FC layers. I used L2 regularization, batch norm, data augmentation and dropout to remove overfitting. I then tried out reducing the learning rate of Adam optimizer as the training progressed. I trained the network for more than 100 epochs and sometimes upto 200 epochs. However, the best validation accuracy(20% of dataset) I could achieve was 71%. Is there anyway out to improve the validation accuracy above 85%?
I used the following architecture with input image size of 256*256*3 and trained them with a batch size of 16.

```
regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.005)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5),strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3), kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(96, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=None),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=None),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=None),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),

    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=None),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
])
```

Comment: You may just not have a big enough dataset. 8200 images is not a ton, and if you don't have enough images to learn a general representation for your task, you are going to have overfitting. Try using transformations on your images to increase your effective number of samples maybe.

Comment: I tried out augmentation like rotations, horizontal flip and changing brightness. That didn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you are using all available forms of data augmentation (scaling, rotation, translation, flips, etc.).
- Use kernel regularizers on all layers.
- Add `SpatialDropout2D` after all Conv layers.
- Add `BatchNormalization` after all Conv and Dense layers (except for the last Dense/sigmoid one, obviously).
- Reduce the size of your network (fewer layers and/or fewer filters/units per layer); you want the smallest possible network that can still learn the training data.

If all of those combined are not enough to get good validation accuracy, then you probably just don't have enough data.

---

A few tips that probably won't reduce overfitting, but tend to be helpful in general:

- Prefer sequences of 3x3 kernel conv layers rather than single conv layers with 5x5 or larger kernels.
- Replace the Flatten layer with a GlobalAveragePooling layer, and probably remove all Dense layers except the last one.
- Use either stride=2 *or* MaxPooling, not both.

Comment: What is the difference between Dropout and Spacial Dropout?

Comment: @SaankhyaMondal See https://keras.io/layers/core/#spatialdropout2d. Essentially, it drops whole "filters" rather than individual elements.